# Should accessor method checks for if the calling object is null in java?

Tags: java

Should I check if the calling object is null?

for instance:

```
public class Some
{
    private int number;
    private String name;

    public Some()
    {
        number = 0;
        name = "no name";
    }

    public String get() 
    {
        return name; //Should I check if the calling object is null?
    }
}
```

Comment: The getters and setters are used to validate the data only.
You can check

Comment: What do you mean by "the calling object"?

Comment: in this case `name` never null because you initialize it in constructor and the variable is private and non-static so you have to create the object to access it.

Comment: Good practice to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getters should not be validating data. You are approaching this from the wrong direction.

First you need to define the *rules* for your object: What are valid values for its parameters? These rules are called invariants.

Then, use the *setters* to validate data, to ensure that the invariants always hold. In other words, *use the setters to ensure that an object that breaks the rules can't exist*.

If you validate in the getters then you are checking for invalid fields *after* the fact. It is already too late at that point to really do anything about it.

Then, barring strange uses of reflection (also deserialization is a separate matter), you are guaranteed that your getters will also return values that do not break the rules. For example, lets say a "person" must have a non-null name, and must have an age that is > 0 and <= 150:

```
class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    // Constructor uses setters to perform validation.
    // Throws IllegalArgumentException on invalid parameter.
    public Person (String name, int age) {
        setName(name);
        setAge(age);
    }

    // Setter validates name.
    public final void setName (String name) {
        if (name == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid name specified.");
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Setter validates age.
    public final void setAge (int age) {
        if (age <= 0 || age > 150)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid age specified."); 
        this.age = age;
    }

    // Guaranteed to return a non-null name.
    public final String getName () {
        return this.name;
    }

    // Guaranteed to return an age > 0 and <= 150.
    public final int getAge () {
        return this.age;
    }

}
```

Also note that I've made the getters and setters `final` here. Since those parameters have rules, this would prevent a subclass from overriding a getter/setter and potentially breaking the invariants we have set for a `Person`.

Answer (score 2):

Only if you want to be holier than the pope.

You should check for nulls when you get the object itself, and only after that call any methods on the objects:

```
if (some == null){
   // do something: send an error message / throw exception / ignore
} else {
    System.out.println(some.get());
    System.out.println(some.getOtherStuff());
    ....
}
```

Comment: If an object with a null (or otherwise inappropriate) value for one of those fields is *invalid*, as per its invariants, then really you would want to validate in the setters so that an object that breaks its invariants can never exist. In those cases, if you wait until you get the value, it is already too late to do something about it.

Answer (score 2):

If by "check if the calling object is null" you mean "check if the result of the `get()` call is `null`", then the answer is, "it depends on your use case."  For your use case, your value from `name` will never be `null`, so there's little gain in checking for it.

Normally, getters are just that - getters.  They only *get* data, even `null`.

If you're going to use that value and you have an expectation of it being non-null, then you most certainly should check for `null` in the method that uses it.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language.if I create a new object of class Some，should I check if the object is null which invokes the method get()?Thank you.

Comment: @JohnSmith Inside the `get()` method it is *impossible* for the object to have been null. See my answer. Your question doesn't make sense, and neither does your choice of accepted answer given this clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by `calling object` you mean the object the method is called on, e.g.

```
String name = callingObject.get();
```

Now `callingObject` becomes `this` inside the method, and `this` can *never* be null inside the `get()` method. If `callingObject` had been null, the JVM would have thrown a `NullPointerException` *before* and *instead of* calling `get().`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not the responsibility of the accessors to validate its own object. 
Simply put it this way : you cannot get the weight of a dog unless there is really a dog.

Instead, it is the responsibility of the method calling the accessors to ensure that the object really exists.

```
public class Lab {
    List<Dog> dogs;

    public float getAveDogWeight() {
         float sum = 0.0f;
         float ave = 0.0f;

         if (null != dogs && dogs.size > 0) {
             for (Dog dog : dogs) {
                 if (null != dog) {
                     sum += dog.getWeight();
                 }
             }
             ave = // calculate ave here
         }

         return ave;
    }
}
```